# Intriguing equality solving Dirichlet problem with Poisson integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it true that

$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Re\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z}\right)\cos{2\theta}\ d\theta = \frac1{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Re\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z}e^{2i\theta}\right)\ d\theta$$

is valid? While solving a Dirichlet problem on the unit disk, my professor suggested that we should consider the function $\Phi(\theta)=\cos{2\theta}+i\sin{2\theta}$ instead of the boundary function $\phi(\theta)=\cos{2\theta}$. Doing the calculations assuming the equality above is correct is giving me a close answer to the correct one (according to solutions), which would be $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$. I'm getting $2x^2-2y^2$...

Comment: No, it is not true.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to approach the integral in the left hand side?

Comment: The simplest way is note that $\cos 2\theta=\Re(z^2)$ for $z=e^{i\theta}\in\mathbb{T}$ so LHS has to be $\Re((x+iy)^2)=x^2-y^2$ by uniqueness.  You could also put $z=x+iy$ immediately in the integrand and evaluate.

Comment: Oh, I think I'm understanding what's happening. Since $\phi(e^{i\theta})=\cos{2\theta}$, $\phi(z)=\Re(z^2)$. Since $\phi(z)=\Re(z^2)$ is harmonic and satisfies the boundary value constraint, by uniqueness this must be the solution to the problem. What I haven't understood is how your last suggestion helps in solving the integral, if I wished to do it.

(there is a mistake in the original post, where $\phi(\theta)$ and $\Phi(\theta)$ are it should be $\phi(e^{i\theta})$ and $\Phi(e^{i\theta})$.